# Django couldn't find urlpath

Tags: python, django, url, django-urls

I tried to go 127.0.0.1:8000/poll/ it doesn't open, but I can go to /poll/20/result.
I just add other urls of poll and base url-> /poll/ stop to be opened.
Before I add to detail,result,vote function/url there were no problem  to open index of poll.

Here are my codes:
In view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, World. You are at the poll index.")

def detail(request, poll_id):
    return HttpResponse("You are looking at poll %s" %poll_id)

def results(request, poll_id):
    return HttpResponse("You are looing at the results of poll %s" % poll_id)

def vote(request, poll_id):
    return HttpResponse("You are voting on poll %s" %poll_id)
```

In Polls/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from polls import views


urlpatterns = patterns( '', 
                   url(r'^Ş', views.index, name='index'),
                   url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
                   url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', views.results,name='results'),
                   url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
              )
```

In mysite/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

   url(r'^$', 'sign_ups.views.home', name='home'),
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

   url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

)
```

Comment: It seems you have to use `127.0.0.1:8000/polls/` instead of `127.0.0.1:8000/poll/` because you have `url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls'))`

Comment: Your question is specific to the /poll path, but the root urls.py route is for /polls. Are you sure you are putting in the correct paths in your browser tests?

Comment: I actually used polls on path. Error massage:                                                         Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/
Using the URLconf defined in come_on.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^$ [name='home']
^admin/
^polls/ ^Ş [name='index']
^polls/ ^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$ [name='detail']
^polls/ ^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$ [name='results']
^polls/ ^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$ [name='vote']
^admin/
The current URL, polls/, didn't match any of these.

Answer (score 0):

In your MySite.urls,

you have mentioned the polls url as `polls` and given the url as `poll`.

Change any one of those to get the app working.